# Excel Formula to Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to write below excel formula into Power BI?

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF('Historical '!$A$3:$X$100687,'Current Year '!$A2,'Historical '!$X$3:$X$100687),"No AUP ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd write an `AVERAGEX()` or `CALCULATE(AVERAGE())` formula with filter conditions that match your `AVERAGIF` condition. You have not given enough information to say much more than that.

Comment: DAX works on columns, so you'd need to know the column names. What's in `'Current Year  '!$A2` is unclear as well. Cell references give no indication of what the columns are.

Comment: Hi Alexis,Historical $A$3 is table,current year and Historical $x$3 are column.I am not sure do i need also need lookup as well.Thanks